# Iterate over full array starting at any position, using only one variable

Tags: c++, algorithm

Fairly simple, I want to loop over every index of an array of `arraysize` using only one var for the loop.  I have a way to do it with two vars `i` and `j`, where `i` tracks the actual index and loops around and `j` counts up to arraysize and terminates the loop:

```
for (unsigned int i = start, j = 0; //start is the starting index
 j < arraysize;
 ++i == arraysize ? i = 0 : 0, ++j)
{
 //do stuff
}
```

Is there some nifty way to do this with only `i`?  Order doesn't matter, if backward iteration makes sense for some reason.

Clarification: I want to loop from `start` to `arraysize - 1`, then from `0` to `start - 1`.

Comment: I don't get it - what's the purpose of `i` here?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you need. Do you want to loop ``arraysize`` times over an array of size ``arraysize``?

Comment: I think he want to iterate over **all** elements, starting from some arbitrary position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would prefer to abstract that algorithm into generic function (which would work even on things like [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list)), without doing superfluous modulo and addition operations (though, they may be acceptable in many cases):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template<typename FwdIter, typename F>
F for_each_shifted(FwdIter first, FwdIter start, FwdIter last, F f)
{
    using std::for_each;
    return for_each(first, start, for_each(start, last, f));
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    int v[] = { 1, 1, 2, 6, 24 };
    for_each_shifted(begin(v), begin(v) + 3, end(v), [](int x)
    {
        cout << x << endl;
    });
}
```

Output is:

```
6
24
1
1
2
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ef7aa42ebe9969b)

Comment: +1. This is the only solution which correctly avoids integer overflow.

Answer (score 7):

At least as I understand it, you want to loop through the entire array, *but* you want to start from somewhere other than the beginning, then when you reach the end, you want to start back at the beginning and keep going until you reach the original starting point.

Assuming that's correct, it's pretty easy:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<arraysize; i++)
    process(array[(i+start)%arraysize]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ( i=start; i<start+arraysize; i++ ) {
    // do stuff with (i % arraysize) in place of i
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (size_t i = start; (i + 1) % arraysize != start: i = (i + 1) % arraysize)  { 
    // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would get you there:

```
for (unsigned int i = start; i < start + arraySize; i++)
{
    DoSomething(array[i % arraySize]);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < arraySize;  i++)
{
    DoSomething(array[(i + start) % arraySize]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use the folloing loop statement

```
for ( int i = start; i < arraysize + start; i++ )
```

and inside the loop body instead of i use expression i % arraysize